# SwifUI: Cannot convert value of type '(Binding<Veggies>) -> VeggiesView' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'

Tags: swift, generics, view, swiftui

```
     class VeggieProperties: Identifiable, ObservableObject 
            {
                //id implementation
                @Published var name: String = ""
                  //inits with random properties for testing purposes
            }
    
           class Veggies: Identifiable, ObservableObject 
        {
            //id implementation
            @Published var name: String = ""
            @Published var properties: [VeggiesProperties] = [VeggiesProperties]
            //inits with random names for testing purposes
        }

    class VeggiesToBuy: Identifiable, ObservableObject
    {
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var veggiesList: [Veggies] = [Veggies]()
    //inits to populate veggiesList with random Veggies for testing purposes
    }

    struct GenericView<Elements, Content>: View where Elements: RandomAccessCollection, Elements.Element: Hashable, Content: View 
{
        var data: Elements
        var content: (Elements.Element) -> Content
        var body: some View {
                   VStack {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { self.content($0)}
            }
        }
    }


struct VeggiesView: View {
    @Binding var veggie: Veggies
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(veggie.name)")
            GenericView(data: veggies.properties) {
                property in
                Text("\(property.name)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error appears right here:

```
struct VeggiesToBuy: View {
   @Binding var veggiesToBuyList: [Veggies]

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
***//            GenericView(data: veggiesToBuyList) { veggies in VeggiesView(veggie: veggies)} <- also doesn't work
            ForEach(self.veggiesToBuyList, id: \.self) {veggies in VeggiesView(veggie: veggies)}***
        }
    }
}
```

From a similar question here, it seems that compiler might not be pointing to towards the exact string that's responsible for the error. In my case it points towards:
***ForEach(self.veggiesToBuyList, id: .self) {veggies in VeggiesView(veggie: veggies)}***
Or the other one with GenericView implementation. Any ideas how to make this work and why exactly does this error pop up?

Comment: VeggiesView works fine.

Comment: Using XCode 11.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model uses reference-type observable objects, so it is more appropriate to use them with `@ObservedObject` than with binding

Here is full fixed code. Tested with Xcode 12.

```
class VeggieProperties: Identifiable, ObservableObject, Hashable
{
    static func == (lhs: VeggieProperties, rhs: VeggieProperties) -> Bool {
        lhs === rhs  // << for simplicity, do as you need
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }

    //id implementation
    @Published var name: String = ""
    //inits with random properties for testing purposes
}

class Veggies: Identifiable, ObservableObject, Hashable
{
    static func == (lhs: Veggies, rhs: Veggies) -> Bool {
        lhs === rhs  // << for simplicity, do as you need
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
        hasher.combine(properties)
    }

    //id implementation
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var properties: [VeggieProperties] = [VeggieProperties]()
    //inits with random names for testing purposes
}

class VeggiesToBuy: Identifiable, ObservableObject
{
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var veggiesList: [Veggies] = [Veggies]()
    //inits to populate veggiesList with random Veggies for testing purposes
}

struct GenericView<Elements, Content>: View where Elements: RandomAccessCollection, Elements.Element: Hashable, Content: View
{
    var data: Elements
    var content: (Elements.Element) -> Content
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { self.content($0)}
        }
    }
}


struct VeggiesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var veggie: Veggies
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(veggie.name)")
            GenericView(data: veggie.properties) {
                property in
                Text("\(property.name)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VeggiesToBuyView: View {
    var veggiesToBuyList: [Veggies]

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            GenericView(data: veggiesToBuyList) { veggies in
                VeggiesView(veggie: veggies)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll be able to test it later. However I last time I tried @ObservedObject it showed the exact same error. Forgot to add, all classes in my code conform to Identifiable and Hashable as well as ObservableObject. Also I’m using XCode 11.3.1, might this be the bug specific to my version of XCode? Also, would using ObservedObject cause the sub views to update when they’re changed within themself?

Comment: I know it does )). You're welcome and welcome on board. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)